# Swift - How do I stop a table from reloading an image if it's the same image as before?

Tags: ios, image, uitableview

I have an application that runs a bunch of json API requests to a server that then loads info and an image alongside that info. The problem is that when I move down across a table and then back up again, it reloads the images with the animation I set (alpha = 0 to 1) and I don't want that since it looks bad. I tried telling the server if the `newImage == cell.imageview.image` but that of course didn't work since it's not the same image in memory. How can I fix this?

The only way I can think of is to subclass or extend the `UIImage` class and add a string that is the link to the image, and then when I'm setting the image, I also check if the links are the same. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep an dictionary/set of indexPaths that have completed the animation. So you check for indexPath in your dictionary just before you add the animation and on animation completion add the indexPath. your code will look something like this:

```
    //in your viewController class
    var animateIndexPaths = Set<NSIndexPath>()

    //tableview delegate
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if !animateIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { 
                    //do your animation
                }, completion: { (stop:Bool) in
                    self.animateIndexPaths.insert(indexPath)
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: So would that be better than extending/subclassing the UIImage class? I feel like creating an entire data container will take more time, especially since I have to clear the set every time I reload the table, which I do a lot.

Comment: I tried doing it with an extension and it didn't work. Turns out that when a new image loads, it asks for the link of the image at the first index. So say for example if I scroll down and `cell2` is out of the view, when I scroll back up and initially reload what is supposed to be `cell2` it reloads as `cell0` because it's at the top of the list. So I'm going to combine ur suggestion with mine and use a dictionary that points to an image for each link loaded. I'll empty that set everytime I reload. Will update when i try it!

Comment: **Final Update:** I used an NSMutableDictionary to store the images that are loaded, and it works perfectly! Thanks a bunch!